# validation on attr_accessor breaks reload at rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an attribute accessor at my **Invoice** model

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :package_ids

  validates :package_ids, presence: true
```

and just now I add **validation presence:true** to it

And now, all test that require to reload an object will fail.
And if I remove the validation, it will pass again.
For example,

```
it 'return Y for valid sig' do
  post :callback, @params
  json_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
  expect(json_response["body"]["result"]).to eq "Y"
  @invoice.reload
  expect(@invoice.payment_amount.to_f).to eq 45.5
  expect(@invoice.is_paid?).to eq true
  expect(@invoice.paid_jompay?).to eq true
end
```

So my question is, why it break reload function?
additional info

```
rails 4.2.5.1
rspec-rails 3.1.0
```

thank you

Comment: Of course, the test fails because when you use reload, ```Attributes are reloaded from the database, and caches busted``` (http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/reload). You might want to try ```allow(@invoice).to receive(:package_ids).and_return([1, 2, 3])```

Comment: That is intended, in the caches, the invoice has no record of payment. 
When I made a post request to the controller, it will update the invoice with some payment record.

So, reload will update the @invoice caches with the updated invoice from the database.

Comment: But I think ```package_ids``` is not stored in the database because you use ```attr_accessor```, right?

Comment: I didn't save that value, package_ids is only meant for referencing to package selected. In the controller, I update the payment_amount, payment_ref and some other thing.

But looks like its not updated. 

Note that it works just fine without the validation on the attr accessor.

Comment: My bad. Its not reload problem. The validation will stop invoice from being updated because attr_accessor doesnt persist. Of course. 
Thank you @TanNguyenNhat for spending your time

Comment: I'm glad you solved it!